# Como mostrar as Options (HTML) com os elementos do Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, aplicação-web

Olá, eu estou querendo fazer o seguinte: Quero que apareça os elementos que estão cadastrados no banco de dados dentro de um "Select - Option (FORM - HTML)".

Ex:

```
<body>
<?php
include("conexa.php");
$id = 80;
$pegadiv = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `dividas` WHERE id_user = '$id'");
while($linha = $pegadiv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$idConta = $linha['id'];
$nomeConta = $linha['descricao'];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<select name="conta">
    <option name="<?php $idConta ?>"> <?php echo $nomeConta?> </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Excluir">
</form>
</body>
```

Esse e jeito que eu estou fazendo, só que assim so aparece a ultima conta listada pelo usuário.

Comment: os seus options precisam ficar dentro do while, da forma que está você está obtendo algum resultado?

Comment: Obtenho sim. Mas só o último cadastrado.

Comment: Quando eu coloco dentro do looping cria um select para cada item cadastrado

Comment: Você chegou testar meu código? como mencionei antes o option precisa estar dentro do looping, a tag <select> precisa estar fora, respeitando <select><looping></select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não entender porque está apenas obtendo o último registro você vai cometer este erro novamente.

Observe exatamente em:

```
while($linha = $pegadiv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $idConta = $linha['id'];
    $nomeConta = $linha['descricao'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Você tem duas variaveis, `$idConta` e `$nomeConta`, logo imagine que faça isso:

```
foreach([1,2,3,4] as $numero){
    $idConta = $numero;
}
```

O que vai ocorrer? O `$idConta` será 1, depois será 2, depois será 3, depois será 4 e acabará o `foreach`. No final você terá o último elemento, `4`.

---

Uma maneira de corrigir isso é fazer:

```
<body>
<?php
include("conexa.php");
$id = 80;
$pegadiv = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `dividas` WHERE id_user = '$id'");

<select name="conta">
    <?php
    while($linha = $pegadiv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <option name="<?= $linha['id'] ?>"> <?= $linha['descricao'] ?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Excluir">
</form>
</body>
```

Dessa forma tudo que está dentro do `while` irá repetir.

Answer (score 1):

Vou fazer uma adpatção em seu código apenas para didática, o conteúdo do option precisa ficar dentro do while.

```
<?php include("conexa.php"); ?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<select name="conta">    
<?php
$id = 80;
$pegadiv = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `dividas` WHERE id_user = '$id'");
    while($linha = $pegadiv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option id=\"{$linha['id']}\" name=\"{$linha['id']}\">{$linha['descricao']}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Excluir">
</form>
</body>
```

como disse é apenas uma forma de resolver.